# Ubuntu Appcelerator - Cannot install node on platforms other than windows or mac

Tags: titanium, ubuntu-14.04, appcelerator

Appc is successfully setup via terminal. Each prerequisite installed but on Studio launch Appcelerator cannot find/recognize installed node and tries to install node again and prompts "cannot install node on platforms other than windows or mac".

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/179072/install-titanium-on-ubuntu-64bit-guide-step-by-step-guide

Comment: No, actually I tried to install it by the official tutorial of appcelerator.com so what do you suggest now?

Comment: try that, or ask in the Q&A section at Appcelerator. This is also off topic on Stackoverflow

Comment: you can also try asking in Slack: http://tislack.org

Comment: Tried this tutorial too but didn't work for me and I have posted the same question in Q&A section at Appcelerator but no response yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using the latest version of Titanium so it requires the latest Node.js (nodejs, node and npm). Appcelerator tries to install node because it does not find any compatible version.

Secondly Appcelerator tries to install all pending prerequisites and it cannot install node on platforms other than windows or mac so you have to install nodejs via terminal.

To debug issues try to run programs via terminal. Particular to Appcelerator in Ubuntu, go the directory and run it by command $ ./AppceleratorStudio
It will prompt all ERRORS, WARNINGS and NOTICES.

Comment: This is not really an answer

Comment: Well that resolved my issue so I posted. I hope that for Ubuntu users it would be helpful. Anyway, thanks for response.